# RESTful reordering of nested objects

Tags: rest, http, nested, restful-url, restful-architecture

I have a RESTful API that supports two objects so as object `A` contains an ordered list of nested objects `B`:

```
Create object A               - POST  /a
Create object B and add to A  - POST  /a/<id>/b
Update object B in A          - PATCH /a/<id>/b/<id>
```

**What would be a RESTful way to update the order of `B` objects in a specific `A`?**

**Option 1:** `PATCH /a/<id>` with json content that replaces `A.Bs`
`A` has a list of embedded `B`s, namely `A.Bs` so you can replace that list in its entirety also changing the order on the way. This relies on the client to resubmit the entire list correctly.

**Option 2:** `PATCH /a/<id>` with json content that replaces `A.B_order`
Add a separate list of `B` ids and have the client update it. This is similar to Option 1 but does not rely on the client resubmitting all the objects. It does require the server to manage the list, updating it upon `B` creation, and validating the update contains all the required `B` ids on list order update.

**Option 3:** `PATCH /a/<id>/b` with json content that replaces `A.Bs`
The same as Option 1, but with a different URL

Which would be most RESTful and clear?
Any other options?

Comment: btw, I'm using `PATCH` for partial updates, instead of `PUT` which replaces the entire object

Comment: why not POST instead?

Comment: @richard POST can also be used for a case like this, but PATCH is more specific/semantically correct than POST and therefore is a slightly better fit.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out the difference between a [tag:restful-url] and a regular one as to me they are actually the same. By that, a client shouldn't interpret URIs but just use them as pointer to a resource. Contrary to common beliefs, the URI itself does not contain any pathing logic and should be used as a whole. You can of course "fake" a pathing logic by providing a set of URIs that in total form a traversable graph. HTTP allows partial updates either through PATCH or by PUT updating an overlapping resource. This has the effect of a partial update to the actual ressource

Comment: Unlike PUT, however, PATCH is actually a method a client can use to send step-by-step instruction on how to modify the current resource to a desired state to the server. The client is actually telling here the server on how to transform the resource instead of presenting it the final output. It is further necessary that either all of the instructions complete successfully or none of them should be applied at all, which requires some transactional requirements to the operation. As Eric and Evert already proposed I'd also recommend to use [JsonPatch](http://jsonpatch.com/) therefore

Comment: You could of course also do it with the order of b's being a resource like /a/order-of-b-Ids, and then it becomes something you can treat as any other resouce.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the proposed standard defined in [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902). Specifically, the "move" op would seem to be what you're looking for.

Comment: nice reference, however for me at least it seems an overkill

Answer (score 0):

Given Foo has Bars and Bars are resources (have ID or link), when you need to reorder foo.bars then I would suggest:

’PUT /foos/:id/bars’ with array of IDs or links in the body.

But if Bars are not resources (have no ID), then:

’PATCH /foos/:id’ with body of Foo including complete new array of Foo.bars in the ’bars’ property.

Answer (score 0):

The question I would ask myself is: "What does 'order' mean in this case".

The specific instances of `B` don't have an order between them. They're all independent resources that are not really 'aware' of each order.

Given that, it's not really the `B` resource that you are changing. What are you changing?

Presumably there is a collection of `B`'s somewhere. You do a `GET` request on that collection to get an ordered list of `B`'s. Do you get that list on `/a/<id>` or on `/a/<id>/b` ?.

Wherever that ordered list is, I would also do the operation to change the order because the order is a 'property' of the collection.

So for the sake of the argument, lets assume that your 'collection of `B` lives on `/a/<id>b`. What format should that be?

Well, a good REST service will replace the entire state. So as a default I would do a `PUT` request on that resource and do a full replace of the entire thing.

If you don't like that idea and want to use `PATCH` to update only a part of the collection (and nothing else), I think I would opt for one of these:

1. Use a standard format, like `json-patch`.
2. Come up with your own syntax to describe this.

Option 2 will likely be a lot simpler to implement, and I would also keep the format as simple as possible.

If you use a format like HAL, a collection is probably a list of links. In that case I would use a syntax like:

```
{
  "_links": {
     "item": [
        { "href": "/a/<id>/b/ordered-item-1" },
        { "href": "/a/<id>/b/ordered-item-2" }
      ]
  }
}
```

If you don't have a hypermedia-style API, you probably use id's and force the client to expand id's in urls. In that case, I'd imagine the format could look like:

```
{
   "items": [ 1, 3, 5, 2]
}
```

In each case, it's a Good Idea to define your own media type for this, because this format for PATCH has special meaning to your api. For example:

```
application/vnd.jonathan.patch+json
```